# webservice SOAP message Monitor or logging

Tags: soap

Could some one tell me how to capture SOAP messages passed between the client and the server webservice applications.

I tried using both tools.
pocket soap
http://www.pocketsoap.com/pocketsoap/

Fiddler
http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/

I may miss some settings, it is not working for me.

help will be more appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [tcpmon](https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/).

[soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) integrates with tcpmon, and may provide a nicer interface for you.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306214/http-request-monitoring-tool#306258); You can try the MS Visual Roundtrip Analyzer analyzer as well.

Answer (score 4):

if you're interested, you can write a handler in Java which extends the GenericSOAPHandler class, and print the output to wherever you like. In this (simple) case, the server log:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class MyHandler extends GenericSOAPHandler {

    private void print(InputStream input, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
        try {
            DocumentBuilder parser;
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = parser.parse(input);
            Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            serializer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
            serializer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(out));
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // A fatal error occurred
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean handleInbound(MessageContext msgContext) {
        SOAPMessageContext soapMessageCtx = (SOAPMessageContext) msgContext;
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = soapMessageCtx.getMessage();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            soapMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
            byte[] array = outputStream.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
            System.out.println("SOAP request message:\n");
            print(inputStream, System.out);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean handleOutbound(MessageContext msgContext) {
        SOAPMessageContext soapMessageCtx = (SOAPMessageContext) msgContext;
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = soapMessageCtx.getMessage();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            soapMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
            byte[] array = outputStream.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
            System.out.println("SOAP response message:\n");
            print(inputStream, System.out);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

You also need to make sure your handler is included in the jaxws-handlers-server.xml of your server implementation:

```
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee javaee_web_services_1_2.xsd">
   <handler-chain>
      <protocol-bindings>##SOAP11_HTTP</protocol-bindings>
      <handler>
         <handler-name>DebugHandler</handler-name>
         <handler-class>handlers.MyHandler</handler-class>
      </handler>
   </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rich, i have been searching for many day for solution like this. U saved my life. Now i can watch my soap request in output and not monitoring ports etc.
For using this u will need to download and add this jar:
Download link:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjbosswsapi100Beta1jar.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here my code in C++ for retrieve xml message using Soap Toolkit 3.0 before sending.

```
.
.
.
   Serializer->EndEnvelope();
/* ___________________ */

    char * bufferxml = NULL;

   _variant_t punt = _variant_t((IUnknown*)Serializer);
   punt.lVal += 48;
   _variant_t punt1 = *punt.ppunkVal;
   punt1.lVal += 32;
   _variant_t punt2 = *punt1.ppunkVal;
   punt2.lVal += 4;
   memcpy(&bufferxml, (char *) *punt2.ppunkVal, sizeof(char *));

   punt2.lVal += 4;
   int lengxml = *(punt2.pintVal);
   bufferxml[lengxml] = '\0';
/* ___________________ */

  // Send the message to the web service
    Connector->EndMessage();      
.
.
.
   punt.Detach();
   punt1.Detach();
   punt2.Detach();
   punt.Clear();
   punt1.Clear();
   punt2.Clear();

   Serializer.Release();
.
.
.
```

I hope really help you,  it´s my design and it had worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is also TCP/IP Monitor which comes bundled with WTP plugin for eclipse which allows you to set up a monitor on a port to look into the SOAP requests.